# Почему grid обрезает последние блоки?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, grid

Всем добрый день. Верстаю новостной сайт и решил попробовать использовать сетку grid , но почему-то сетка становиться не во весь размер блоков и обрезает часть последних элементов . Гуглил , но не нашёл решение проблемы. Помогите пожалуйста , заранее спасибо. Вот ссылка на codepen https://codepen.io/Daniil-chaynik/pen/wvdzNbE .

```css
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .second-Bar {
                /* margin-top: 2rem; */
                display: grid;
                align-items: center;
                grid-template-columns: 36% 1fr 1fr 1fr;
                grid-template-areas:
                    'card-1 card-2 card-3 card-4'
                    'card-1 card-5 card-6 card-7';
                grid-column-gap: 7%;
                grid-row-gap: 3%;
                position: relative;
                justify-content: space-between;
                background-color: black;
            }
            .card {
                position: relative;
            }
            .image-block {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .image {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                aspect-ratio: 3 / 2;
                background-color: gray;
            }
            .about {
                position: relative;
                margin-top: 0.4rem;
                text-align: center;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: space-between;
            }
            .text {
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 600;
                font-size: 1em;
                line-height: 1.3;
                color: white;
            }
            .time {
                position: relative;
                font-family: Roboto;
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-size: 1em;
                line-height: 1;
                color: red;
                padding-top: 0.6rem;
            }
```

```html
        <div class="second-Bar">
            <div class="card" style="grid-area: card-1">
                <div class="image-block">
                    <img src="" alt="" class="image" />
                </div>
                <div class="about">
                    <h1 class="text">
                        Сегодня завершится первый тур группового этапа Кубка
                        Узбекистана. .
                    </h1>
                    <h2 class="time">08.05.2021, 22:57</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="grid-area: card-2">
                <div class="image-block">
                    <img src="" alt="" class="image" />
                </div>
                <div class="about">
                    <h1 class="text">
                        Сегодня завершится первый тур группового этапа Кубка
                        Узбекистана. .
                    </h1>
                    <h2 class="time">08.05.2021, 22:57</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="grid-area: card-3">
                <div class="image-block">
                    <img src="" alt="" class="image" />
                </div>
                <div class="about">
                    <h1 class="text">
                        Сегодня завершится первый тур группового этапа Кубка
                        Узбекистана. .
                    </h1>
                    <h2 class="time">08.05.2021, 22:57</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="grid-area: card-4">
                <div class="image-block">
                    <img src="" alt="" class="image" />
                </div>
                <div class="about">
                    <h1 class="text">
                        Сегодня завершится первый тур группового этапа Кубка
                        Узбекистана. .
                    </h1>
                    <h2 class="time">08.05.2021, 22:57</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="grid-area: card-5">
                <div class="image-block">
                    <img src="" alt="" class="image" />
                </div>
                <div class="about">
                    <h1 class="text">
                        Сегодня завершится первый тур группового этапа Кубка
                        Узбекистана. .
                    </h1>
                    <h2 class="time">08.05.2021, 22:57</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="grid-area: card-6">
                <div class="image-block">
                    <img src="" alt="" class="image" />
                </div>
                <div class="about">
                    <h1 class="text">
                        Сегодня завершится первый тур группового этапа Кубка
                        Узбекистана. .
                    </h1>
                    <h2 class="time">08.05.2021, 22:57</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" style="grid-area: card-7">
                <div class="image-block">
                    <img src="" alt="" class="image" />
                </div>
                <div class="about">
                    <h1 class="text">
                        Сегодня завершится первый тур группового этапа Кубка
                        Узбекистана. .
                    </h1>
                    <h2 class="time">08.05.2021, 22:57</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Там видимо порядок расчётов такой, что сначала вычисляется размер грида из того, что можно вычислить. При вертикальных гэпах в процентах, не понятно как брать этот процент при неуказанных высотах рядов, и он поэтому берётся позже от ранее рассчитанной высоты. Эти гэпы выталкивают ряды вниз. Если сделать вертикальные гэпы в пикселях, то проблемы нет. Но это только мои рассуждения.

Comment: Я верно предположил. Здесь есть такой же пример - https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example36/ , а здесь участники явно говорят это - https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/345#issuecomment-240333816

Comment: @PavelGrishaev да действительно нельзя использовать grid gap в процентах , спасибо большое. Черканите , чтоб я смог отменить ваше решение вопроса.

Comment: Да и так сойдёт, видно ж всем коменты, а репутация тут особого значения не имеет.